# Chrome Web Extension Background Authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome-extension, msal.js

I am building a Chrome Web Extension that uses '@azure/msal-browser' to authenticate users into the app ultisiing chrome.identity and Microsoft oAuth authentication.

When a user opens the extension it asks them to login and the authorisation flow returns an access token which we use in our API requests. This is working.

I want to add a feature where if a user has previously logged in, the chrome extension will silently log them in in the background, without the user opening the extension. This is so the chrome extension can retrieve data from our API layer without the user having to open the extension each time.

I have tried to store the refresh token, however that is not returned via the api call. I have tried both acquireTokenSilent & ssoSilent but they return error "Login and token requests are not supported in non-browser environments."

Is there a way of authenitcating users using chrome.identiy without a browser interaction?

#### Relevant code

Sign in flow:

```
export const signIn = async () => {
  await msalInstance.initialize()
  const url = await getLoginUrl()
  
  const { accessToken } = await launchWebAuthFlow(url)
  if (accessToken) {
    await getPowerTesterToken(accessToken)
  } else {
    throw new Error('Error Logging in')
  }
}

export const signInSilent = async () => {
  console.log('Trying to acquire silent token')
  await msalInstance.initialize()
  try {
    // Set currently logged in account
    const { accessToken } = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes: ['openid", "profile'],
      loginHint: getAccounts(),
    })

    await getPowerTesterToken(accessToken)

    return true // return true to state its succesful
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('signInSilent Error', err)
  }
}

export const getAccounts = () => {
  // Set currently logged in account
  const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()
  if (accounts.length) {
    return accounts[0]
  }
}

/**
 * Generates a login url
 */
async function getLoginUrl(request, reject) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    msalInstance
      .loginRedirect({
        ...request,
        onRedirectNavigate: (url) => {
          resolve(url)
          return false
        },
      })
      .catch(reject)
  })
}

async function launchWebAuthFlow(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
      {
        interactive: true,
        url,
      },
      (responseUrl) => {
        // Response urls includes a hash (login, acquire token calls)
        if (responseUrl.includes('#')) {
          msalInstance
            .handleRedirectPromise(`#${responseUrl.split('#')[1]}`)
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject)
        } else {
          // Logout calls
          resolve()
        }
      },
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm leaning towards either creating a access token specific for the extension that has a long expiry or add API key authorisation to the application